# Is it possible to detect when a application closes in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need a way to figure out if an application I launch from a bash script has finished and closed so I may clean up after it.

**Is there a way to detect this when launching the application from a script? Is there a function that will run the application and then block the script until the called application has finished and returned?**

The purpose for this is to unlock luks partitions, launch an application that will use the data stored on them, and then once that application returns to clean up and lock the luks partitions.

Thanks.

Comment: Read about the `wait` job control command in [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Builtins).

Comment: Only one question per question, please: The temporary-privilege-escalation question should be asked separately.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Waiting for each command to finish is the normal behavior (if you don't use & and the program doesn't do anything unusual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this works for your first question:

```
list=$(ls -l1)
echo "ls output: $list"
```

The `echo` command will wait until the command inside `$(` and `)` finishes.

For your second question, a better way would be (if you have sudo permissions):

```
sudo su -c 'echo "hi from $(whoami)"'
echo "hi from $(whoami)"
```

Comment: Capturing the output of the command is not needed as long as it blocks the script from running until the called application has returned. Also thanks for the sudo answer.

Comment: Re: second question -- more than one question to a question is out of line w/ site rules (see meta). The OP should be encouraged to ask separately (at which point you can answer separately, and get additional rep as well) should there be no separate dupes.

Comment: @randynewfield Usually, commands in a script are executed sequentially, unless you launch your program in background.